# laravel 5 dynamic mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how can I change the database in Laravel dynamic? Lets say we have the following variables:

- $host (MySQL hostname / IP)
- $user (MySQL user name)
- $name (MySQL database name)
- $pass (MySQL user password)

How can I connect to this mysql server in Laravel 5 without setting it every time in the config?

Greetings

Comment: in the `.env` file?

Comment: @jycr753 ah no, I get this variables from my internal database, which is set in the **.env**. But I need to connect to external databases with the variables and I cannot set every server in the config (+200), because users delete their servers or add new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this assuming a model `Book`

```html
use Book;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function configureDatabase($database){
        Config::set("database.connections.$database", array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => "$database",
            'username'  => 'root',//User name here
            'password'  => '***', //Password here
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ));
    }

public function getBooks($database){
  $this->configureDatabase($database)
  return Book::on($database)->all();
}
```

Comment: Can I use the config use nearly unlimited times in one execution? Is config::set limited?

Comment: Sure you can. The docs doesn't say the call to Config::set() is limited. Bear in mind that, it is creating a new connection to a different database which is an expensive computation.

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer why my question was downvoted? What was wrong? No code? For this question I think there is no code needed.